# Get addresses of transfers from transactions Web3Py

Tags: transactions, web3.py, addresses, decoding

I am facing issue while trying to retreive data from Goerli (basically, Ethereum). I am trying to fetch transaction [from this contract](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x554ed5BA071205eDC6d9a5BdF86a1E93cBC3AD2c). For every transaction it creates a new airdrop by creating a new smart contract. The address of the new smart contract is highlighted in this picture, by clicking on any of the transactions executed from the main contract:
[image: what To Get]
My aim is to get that address. I try to do it with the following code, where I basically read and decode the input data, but I can't display the contract:

```
def decode_tx(address, txs, node_url, explorer_url, api_key):
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(node_url))
    
    abi_endpoint = f"{explorer_url}?module=contract&action=getabi&address={address}&apikey={api_key}"
    
    abi = json.loads(requests.get(abi_endpoint).text)
    contract = web3.eth.contract(address=Web3.toChecksumAddress(address), abi=abi["result"])
    for tx in txs:
        print(contract.decode_function_input(tx[0]))
        func_obj, func_params = contract.decode_function_input(tx[0])
        tx.extend([str(func_obj), str(func_params)])

    return txs
```

Someone can help me? Thank you.